# Drag and drop for QTreeView doesnt work

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I have been following [this tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views) to be able to drag & drop items of `QTreeView`.

I have done all described steps -- overrided methods of model:

```
class DragAndDropModel : public QFileSystemModel
{
public:
    DragAndDropModel(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QFileSystemModel(parent) {}

    Qt::DropActions supportedDropActions() const override
    {
        return Qt::CopyAction | Qt::MoveAction;
    }

    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const override
    {
        if (!index.isValid())
            return 0;

        return Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | QAbstractItemModel::flags(index);
    }
};
```

Then set this model to `QTreeView` instance and enabled drag & drop

```
m_model->setRootPath(path);
m_treeView->setModel(m_model);
m_treeView->setRootIndex(m_model->index(path));

m_treeView->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
m_treeView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
m_treeView->setDragEnabled(true);
m_treeView->setAcceptDrops(true);
m_treeView->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
```

animations works just well, but after item is dropped, nothing happens. May somebody point me to right direction ?

Comment: in the case of QFileSystemModel it is a special case because it not only modifies virtual data but also real data as the position of a file or directory within the file tree that the OS handles. So you will have to make some special modifications, for example if you drag a file to a folder it is normal that the file is placed inside the folder, what happens if it is dragged from one folder to another folder? and from a folder to a file?

Comment: So what you have described (moving file in filesystem), should be implemented in overrided `dropMimeData` right ?

Comment: I do not know if in dropMimeData (I'm just going to find the right method when you answer the previous question) but your task is to implement the movement of files or directories.

Comment: If some folder A is dragged to another folder B, it should be copied in file system like that -- folder B should contain folder A. Folder dragged to a file should do nothing.

Comment: Qt4 or Qt5 ?, since you point to a Qt4 documentation

Comment: I just reviewed QFileSystemModel and I see that if I support certain functionality but for this you should use: `m_model->setReadOnly(false);`, Tell me if the behavior is what you want.

Comment: It works. It is so obvious, i cant believe i've overlooked it :/ Could you please post it as an answer, so i may accept it and close this thread ?